# How to protect a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, installation, copy-protection

I've a web application( ASP.NET WebForms). Now I need to give this application to my client for offline(Installed on Local Server and accessed via LAN) installation. I want to protect this application from being copied.

All I can think of now is:

> I should maintain a online server and have a Activation Page which
>   runs when the Web App is run for the first time, It should connect to
>   the server and get a valid license against a Key(entered by me in
>   Web.Config during installation) and machine parameters.

Also, if I code it I need to take care of System Clock and other naive issues.

Now, I have two questions.

1. Are there any other options to safe guard a web app?
2. Does the solution I'm planning to code, already exists?

Thanks for reading and trying to help.
:)

Comment: you could just get mac address of the server where it should run, and add a mac address check in app

Comment: I was planning of MAC address and other machine params. MAC address is extremely easy to change in Windows and Other OS.

Comment: well... as rufanov said, there is really no 100% secure way to do this, You could use some hash of mac/ip/activation code/processor serial number/... but you are never really safe

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no.. You can't tottaly protect your ASP.NET app like this..

Customer(if want to) can decompile your code and replace your activation methods, so application will allways think that it's "legally activated", or for example he can write fake activation server that will always activate your software...  It's not so hard really, especially when your application is based on .NET.

This "protections" main purpose is only to make illegal copies creation little longer to do(for servial weeks or month-two..), so your selling departament can sell many-many copies to legal customers, and losses from illegall usage can be not so huge at project start time.. Or can be huge anyway even with usage of "super-super-super commercial protection product for you apps".. It's depends on luck and populariry of your app..

Only, and ONLY way protect your ASP.NET application with 100% guaranty from illegal copying is.. NOT TO give application to client for local install's at all. Use SSAS-model for selling your app. Or if it's not posible make this for some critical parts of your application.

Comment: I'm targeting a vast market and there, only 25% clients have good/constant internet access. Rest, will go for offline version of WebApp. I'm less afraid of customers. But, I'm more afraid of my resellers(who themselves are a IT company). They will not miss a chance to crack the product and sell as theirs.